# Such a strange error while uploading a image file

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 30000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Looks Great!";

    if (file_exists("localhost/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "localhost/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "localhost/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Something went wrong.";
  }
?>
```

This is the upload.php i'm using to upload an image file (jpg) to the folder called upload. I have a form elsewhere and when i choose the file and hit upload....it redirects me to upload.php and i get a message like "Something went wrong" always. I even tried png file..
Can u help?

Comment: Such a strange question, you should just break the `4 or conditions`, and test it condition-by-condition ?

Comment: For png you need to add "image/png" check also.

Comment: Maybe a `var_dump($_FILES);` can help.

Comment: Leaving aside the error, the cause of which should be obvious) are you aware of the dangers of accepting the mimetype asserted by the client?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty much the same as from W3Schools (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) so I would say go back to that site and grab the code again. Also, if you used a PNG fine it would never pass your initial validation since it is not represented in your initial if..else statement.

What I would do here is step through the code and debug:

- Does the form contain the proper file upload element with a name of 'file' on the HTML page?
- Is the file's size less than 30kb?
- Is the image type a gif or jpg?
- Is the image making its way into the `$_FILES` object? Try doing a `print_r` on `$_FILES` to be sure
- Do you have permission to store the image in the server's temp directory?

Good luck with tracking down the issue.

Comment: i need another help...say i upload the file successfully, how do i retrieve the file back using php?

Comment: This code is the most basic way of file upload scripts. You should really consider either renaming the file when it is uploaded or putting a given user's file upload into their own folder. Over time the potential for a file name conflict greatly increases when you don't rename the file names. If you do file renaming then you will always have the name of the file and also avoid future file conflicts.

@symcbean if you have code for something that is more secure than using the mimetype asserted by the client please post or link to it so that we can help get this as solid as possible for Jack

Answer (score 0):

My bet goes on the form missing the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute.

A little styling tip, you could replace the

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 30000))
```

By

```
if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], 
            array("image/gif", 
                  "image/jpg", 
                  "image/pjpeg")) && 
   $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 30000)
```